# How extract phone Number from script with Xpath

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

(Scrapy)I need help with the next code:

```
def parse_item(self, response):

        ml_item = MercadoItem()
        #info de producto
        ml_item['nombre'] = response.xpath('//h1[@class="title"]/text()').extract()
        ml_item['web'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[4]/a/@href').extract()
        ml_item['datos'] = response.xpath('string(/html/head/script[3]/text()').extract() 
        ml_item['direccion'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[2]/text()').extract()


        self.item_count += 1
        if self.item_count > 5:
            raise CloseSpider('item_exceeded')
        yield ml_item
```

ml-item['datos'] is the script contains the phone number, i need extract only phone number, i try extract with regex and xpath but i cant do it.
The script contains a lot of info, but i only need a phone number, i need extract it with a regex expresion because the phone number change in the next page.
The script is:

```
{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"LocalBusiness","name":"Clínica Dental Castellana 23","description":".TU CLÍNICA DENTAL DE REFERENCIA EN MADRID","telephone":"+34912298837","address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","streetAddress":"Castellana 23","addressLocality":"MADRID","addressRegion":"Madrid","postalCode":"28003"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Data in your `script` tag saved in JSON format.
It can be converted into python data scruture with python built-in `json` module

```
import json
.....


def parse_item(self, response):
    ....
    script_data = response.xpath('string(/html/head/script[3]/text()').extract()
    decoded_data = json.loads(script_data)
    ml_item['datos'] = decoded_data["telephone"]
```

Comment: I try it but ml_item['direccion'] = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[2]/text()').extract()
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: IndentationError means that your code line has incorrect number of spaces before code.

Comment: i talk u on Telegram, i review my code but i dont know the error :(